# Java get outer class from inner class?

Tags: java, class

In java, if you have a class (non static) and then an inner class inside it (also non static), how can you get a reference to the outer class object from the inner class?

```
public class Fish {
     public class Fin {
           Fish fish = _____;
     }
}
```

I want to store the Fish object in the variable `fish` in the Fin class.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use

```
Outer.this
```

In your case

```
Fish.this
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would use the class name when the class is not static. Also why doesn't something like `super.this` work?

Comment: @omega `super` refers to the superclass, not the containing class, so changing its semantics for this one case would almost certainly be rejected during language design. `super.this` is also somewhat contradictory -- you can't try to get something from the superclass's namespace and the current object's namespace simultaneously. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @omega Also, the class name here doesn't really have anything to do with static/nonstatic things; it's just a way to differentiate `this` for the inner class and `this` for the containing class, as inner classes have access to the containing class's methods.

Comment: @omega In addition, you can nest as many inner classes as you want, and refer to as many levels up in the nested-ness as you want with this syntax.